# Open dialog when changing page from menu in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, modal-dialog

I have an Angular 4 application. On one page (editionPage) I want to open a dialog to confirm save or not before leaving the page.

So, I have a button to go on the previous page. When I click on this button, I open the dialog.

But I also want to open the dialog when I click on the button from the sidebar menu.

This is my sidebar menu :

```
<nav class="sidebar" [ngClass]="{sidebarPushRight: isActive}">
<ul class="list-group">
    <a routerLink="/first" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item">
        <div class="titleMenu first" >{{ 'first' | translate }}</div>
    </a>
    <a routerLink="/tests" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item">
        <div class="titleMenu">{{ 'Tests' | translate }}</div>
    </a>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And I open my modal dialog like this :

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(DialogSaveEditComponent);
```

I tried to use a guard with `CanDeactivate` but it's not working like I want because I can return the right boolean after the dialog opening so, in background the page change before choose the option or the background never change.

Do you have an idea how I can do that ?

**EDIT**
Now I call a function that open a dialog when I click on a button from the menu. But because of `routerLink="/first" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']"` the page change and then the dialog appears. How can I do to change page after click on a button from the dialog or cancel the changing page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I succeeded what I want to do by using a guard to prevent the user to change page.

This is the new guard :

```
@Injectable()
export class SaveEditGuard implements CanDeactivate<ConfirmDialogSaveBatch> {
    sub: Subscription;
    result: boolean;

constructor(private router: Router, private confirmDialogService: ConfirmDialogSaveBatchService, private datasService: DatasService) {

}

canDeactivate(component: ConfirmDialogSaveBatch, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
              nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if(!this.datasService.clickOnSaveButton){
        this.confirmDialogService.confirm();
    }

    return this.datasService.returnSaveEditValue$;
}
}
```

So, in the case teh user click on the save button, I don't want to display the dialog. So, when I click on the saveButton, I put `this.datasService.clickOnSaveButton`to true and `returnSaveEditValue`to true, so we can quit the page.

If the user quit the page by clicking on the menu, the dialog is opening and wait for the response because of a `ReplaySubject<boolean>`.

This is the code in the service :

```
public returnSaveEditValue = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
public clickOnSaveButton: boolean = false;


public notifyRefreshDatas(data: any) {
    if (data) {
        this.subject.next(data);
    }
}

setReturnSaveEditValue(val: boolean){
    this.returnSaveEditValue.next(val);
}

get returnSaveEditValue$() {
    return this.returnSaveEditValue.asObservable();
}
```

If the user click on save, I put the observable variable to true with the previous function : `this.datasService.setReturnSaveEditValue(true);`
And when the user comes on the page or display a new dialog, I reinitialize the `ReplaySubject` : `this.datasService.returnSaveEditValue = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);`, so if the user click on cancel and want to quit the page again after, the observable variable is again not initialized, so te app wait for the response from the dialog.

And to call the dialog from anywhere, I created a service for the dialog. In this service, I have a function which call and open the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this 
catch the end of navigation, when your navigation end from

```
this.router.events.subscribe(
        res => {
            if(res instanceof NavigationEnd && res.url.startsWith('YOUR URL')) {
               //SHOW YOUR MODAL
            } 
        }
    )
```

Comment: This is not working because the url is the final url and not the start url.

Comment: "So, I have a button to go on the previous page. When I click on this button, I open the dialog." => so it's not the same page no ?

Comment: Else you just have to make the result url open the dialog, you can also do this from a parent of this view

Comment: The dialog is opened a the editionPage. All the actions starts from this page. I want to open the dialog when I click on the buttons from the sidebar menu too. And I want to display the dialog before changing page. When we choose an option in the dialog the page need to change or not.

Comment: SO you were right, use a guard to prevent navigation

Comment: Yes, but even with a guard it's not working... Do you know how to do with a guard ?